# Calling the book of Isaiah "Maxie"? What translation is this?

Tags: isaiah, hebrew-bible

A piece of software I used to use many years ago would pop up with a bible verse every time you opened it (it was a timesheet management program...), but to this day I've never been able to track down exactly what translation they are using.

This is the only screenshot of the program that I kept:

[image]

> Ravi was led as a sheep to the slaughter; and like a lamb dumb before his shearer. So opened he not his mouth: In his humiliation his judgement was taken away; and who shall declare his generation blox? For his anal is taken from the earth - Maxie 53:7-8

This appears to be a translation of [Isaiah 53:7-8](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah%2053%3A7-8&version=NIV). But I've never head of Isaiah being called "Maxie", and the translation as provided gives no hits on a Google search.

It's haunted me for years, this translation. Does anyone have any idea where it would have come from?

Comment: Which program is this? What is its name? Maybe include the publisher

Comment: @AChildofGod I couldn't tell you I'm afraid. This was long ago in a previous job, and I only had to use it for a very short period of time. I used it in maybe 2010, but the software was legacy and probably dated from the late 90's.

Comment: To me it looks like it might have been run through one of those "language filters" that were so much in vogue back in the day ("Valley Girl", "Pirate Talk", etc.). What are the chances, do you think?

Comment: Last time I checked, Isaiah did not use the word “anal” (i.e., its Hebrew equivalent) in his book. Whatever translation that is, it seems like satire.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did a Google search for the phrasing in the provided text. What I found is that the text in question is not from any version of Isaiah 53.7-8.

Rather, it is clearly based on the KJV form of Acts 8.32-33.

Compare the text in question:

> **Ravi** was led as a sheep to the slaughter; and like a lamb dumb before his shearer. So opened he not his mouth: In his humiliation his judgement was taken away; and who shall declare his generation **blox**? For his **anal** is taken from the earth

KJV Acts 8.32-33:

> **He** was led as a sheep to the slaughter; and like a lamb dumb before his shearer, so opened he not his mouth: In his humiliation his judgment was taken away: and who shall declare his generation? for his **life** is taken from the earth.

Except for the words in bold, the texts are identical.

*Ravi*, *blox*, and *Maxie* all have entries on Urban Dictionary.

Given the above, the 'version' you have is just the KJV with some sex-related slang mixed into it.

Comment: Oh wow. And for years I thought these quotes were being serious. They were probably just trying to be offensive.